# Ruby inheritance - child instance has only parent attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, subclass

it is my first time using Ruby subclass inheritence.
I have a parent class A with an attribute "name:string",
and a child class B < A with an attribute "bankname:string".

When I use rails console to create a B instance (B.new) I get an object with "name:string" only, and without the "bankname:string" attribute.

My Schema looks like this:

```
 create_table "a", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "b", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "bankname"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end
```

My models are:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
end

class B < A
end
```

Console:

```
2.4.0 :010 > c = B.new
 => #<B id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: Why `force: :cascade`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby you an really only inherit from another class if you're using [Single Table Inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html), that is two types that share a common table and the table has a string `type` column.

Since you're declaring `B` to be a subclass of `A`, ActiveRecord takes that to mean the `b` table is irrelevant, that `B` uses the `A` table.

What you need is:

```
create_table "a", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "type"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "bankname"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Where now you can accommodate STI. Note that all columns are visible to all models, but you can make "bankname" optional for A, or just ignore it, leave it unused.